# kubectl does not output the logs

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I print all of my Pods with:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

and the output is:

```
NAMESPACE             NAME                                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE  
calico-system         calico-kube-controllers-7487d7f956-hx4fp              1/1     Running   0          88m  
calico-system         calico-node-vn52p                                     1/1     Running   0          88m  
calico-system         calico-typha-7588984c44-m6tsz                         1/1     Running   0          88m  
gitlab-managed-apps   install-ingress                                       0/1     Error     0          14m********  
gitlab-managed-apps   install-prometheus                                    0/1     Error     0          12m  
kube-system           coredns-f9fd979d6-2n2pg                               1/1     Running   0          91m  
kube-system           coredns-f9fd979d6-sq9bl                               1/1     Running   0          91m  
kube-system           etcd-tuoputuo-iamnotstone-server                      1/1     Running   0          91m  
kube-system           kube-apiserver-tuoputuo-iamnotstone-server            1/1     Running   0          91m  
kube-system           kube-controller-manager-tuoputuo-iamnotstone-server   1/1     Running   0          91m  
kube-system           kube-proxy-87jkr                                      1/1     Running   0          91m  
kube-system           kube-scheduler-tuoputuo-iamnotstone-server            1/1     Running   0          91m  
tigera-operator       tigera-operator-58f56c4958-4x9tp                      1/1     Running   0          89m
```

But when I execute the logs command:

```
$ kubectl logs -f install-ingress
```

I see this error

```
Error from server (NotFound): pods "install-ingress" not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `install-ingress` pod is in `gitlab-managed-apps` namespace. If you do not specify namespace in the `kubectl` command then it will search for the pod in **default namespace** where the `install-ingress` pod is not present.

Could you try below command (specifying the namespace of the pod).

```
kubectl logs -f install-ingress -n gitlab-managed-apps
```